# How to include the function (inside the array object) in the DOM element through the for of loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to show the countdown timer function in the browser display of item card element.
I have created the array of objects with key value pairs in it. I have count down timer function included in the array as well, I have managed to show the timer in one item card (picture attached) but struggling to find out how can I show that timer function in all item cards.
codes are here:--

```js
let products = {
    data: [   
       { 
        productName: "Orange",
        catagory: "Fruits",
        price: "5 / kg",
        image: "orange1.jpg",
        desc: "Freshly Picked Oranges",
        timer: setInterval('updateTimer()', 1000)
      },
      { 
        productName: "Apple",
        catagory: "Fruits",
        price: "4 / kg",
        image: "apple.jpg",
        desc: "Freshly Picked Apple",
        timer: setInterval('updateTimer()', 1000)
      },
      { 
        productName: "Pear",
        catagory: "Fruits",
        price: "6 / kg",
        image: "pear1.jpg",
        desc: "Freshly Picked Pear",
      },
      { 
        productName: "Banana",
        catagory: "Fruits",
        price: "4 / kg",
        image: "banana1.jpg",
        desc: "Freshly Picked Banana",
      }
]
};


    for (let i of products.data) {
  
  let card = document.createElement("div");

 
  card.classList.add("card", i.catagory, "hide");
 
  let imgContainer = document.createElement("div");

  imgContainer.classList.add("image-container");
 
  let image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", i.image);
  imgContainer.appendChild(image);
  card.appendChild(imgContainer);
 
  let container = document.createElement("div");
  container.classList.add("container");
  
  let name = document.createElement("h4");
  name.classList.add("product-name");
  name.innerText = i.productName.toUpperCase();
  container.appendChild(name);
  
  let desc = document.createElement("h5");
  desc.innerText = i.desc;
  container.appendChild(desc);
 
  let price = document.createElement("h4");
  price.innerText ="£" + i.price;
  container.appendChild(price);
  
  let timer = document.createElement("h3");
  timer.setAttribute("id", "timer");
  container.appendChild(timer);
  card.appendChild(container);
  document.getElementById("products").appendChild(card);
  
 }


  function updateTimer() {
  
  future = Date.parse("apr 28, 2022 15:05:00");
  now = new Date();
  diff = future - now;

  days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
  secs = Math.floor(diff / 1000);

  d = days;
  h = hours - days * 24;
  m = mins - hours * 60;
  s = secs - mins * 60;

  document.getElementById("timer")
      .innerHTML =
      '<div>' + d + '<span>Days</span></div>' +
      '<div>' + h + '<span>Hrs</span></div>' +
      '<div>' + m + '<span>Mins</span></div>' +
      '<div>' + s + '<span>Secs</span></div>';
      
  if (diff < 0) {
    clearInterval(setInterval('updateTimer()', 1000));
    document.getElementById("timer")
      innerHTML = `<h4 style="color:red" class="expired">sorry, this item has expired!</h4>`;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wraper">
        <div id="search-container">
            <input type="search" name="" id="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
            <button id="search">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('all')">All</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Fruits')">Fruits</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Vegetable')">Vegetable</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Dairy')">Dairy</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Bakery')">Bakery</button>
        </div>
        <div id="products"></div>
        <!-- <div id="timer">0</div> -->
        
    
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

[picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qyC7.png)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("timer")` only returns the first timer it finds. Which, since ids should be unique, should be OK, but you want to create multiple of these, so you should probably use classes which can be repeated. As-is you cannot use multiple ids and this `getElementByID()` method.

So, if you have

```html
<div class="timer" data-expiration="123456789">10 minutes</div>
```

Or something like that, you can then iterate over all timers with something like.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.timer').forEach(timer => {
  // update time.
});
```

---

Updated here from question in the comments.

Simple example to give some ideas. This isn't exactly your code since I think it will be easier to understand without all the other things going on. Hopefully this gives you a sense of how to query for elements, iterate over them, set and clear intervals, and set and update properties on JS element objects.

```js
// This demonstrates the use of `querySelectorAll` using a class on an element. This also shows how you can iterate the resulting list with `forEach`.
document.querySelectorAll('.timer').forEach(timer => {
  // It is helpful to store the function so that we can pass it later to `setInterval`.
  function updateTimer(timer) {
    // Later we will store the current time as a property on our timer objects.
    timer.currentTime -= 1;

    timer.innerHTML = timer.currentTime;

    // To clear a `setInterval`, you need to pass the ID. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval. So, later we will store that on the timer object.
    if (timer.currentTime === 0) {
      clearTimeout(timer.updateIntervalID);
    }
  }

  // We store the current time as mentioned above, so we can easily access it later.
  // I didn't want to write date parsing, so this simply gets the attribute and counts down from that as an integer.
  timer.currentTime = parseInt(timer.getAttribute('data-expiration'));

  timer.innerHTML = timer.currentTime;

  // See above. Here we set the ID from setInterval which is needed to clear it when we are done with the timer.
  timer.updateIntervalID = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000, timer);
});
```

```html
<!-- We cannot use ID the way it is in the code since only one element is allowed to have a specific ID. We can use class which can be used more than onece. -->
<div class="timer" data-expiration="500"></div>
<div class="timer" data-expiration="5"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dan, But I actually wanted to iterate the timer function in my existing for of loop and then append in the individual item card as of other texts and pictures have been appended. Could you help me please.

Comment: I added an example, hopefully that gives you some direction. FWIW, I don't see for loops very often since many objects have methods that allow you to iterate such as the `forEach` shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only have one instance of `Timer` but you need multiple independent instances as different products may have different offers. Your modifying your one instance from multiple items. You could use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for this kind of thing. Here a class `Timer` which implements what you want.

It takes an `endDate` and and `HTMLElement` which it is attached to and then shows a timer. Every time you need a timer you then just have to create an HTML element for it and a new instance of `Timer`.

```js
class Timer {
    #end;
    #attached;
    #interval;

    /**
     *
     * @param {string} endTime Dates string (or other values that can be parsed to Date() constructor)
     * @param {HTMLElement} attachTo HTML element this timer is attached to
     */
    constructor(endTime, attachTo) {
        this.#end = new Date(endTime);
        this.#attached = attachTo;
    }
  
    start() {
      // start timer interval
      this.#interval = setInterval(() => this.updateTimer(), 1000);
    }
  
    stop() {
      // stop the timer
      clearInterval(this.#interval);
    }
  
    updateTimer() {
      const diff = this.#end - new Date();
  
      const days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      const hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      const mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
      const secs = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
  
      const d = days;
      const h = hours - days * 24;
      const m = mins - hours * 60;
      const s = secs - mins * 60;
  
      if(this.#attached){
          this.#attached.innerHTML =
            "<div>" +
            d +
            "<span>Days</span></div>" +
            "<div>" +
            h +
            "<span>Hrs</span></div>" +
            "<div>" +
            m +
            "<span>Mins</span></div>" +
            "<div>" +
            s +
            "<span>Secs</span></div>";
      
          if (diff < 0) {
            this.stop();
            this.#attached.innerHTML = `<h4 style="color:red" class="expired">sorry, this item has expired!</h4>`;
          }
      }
    }
  }
  

let products = {
  data: [
    {
      productName: "Orange",
      catagory: "Fruits",
      price: "5 / kg",
      image: "orange1.jpg",
      desc: "Freshly Picked Oranges",
      offerUntil: new Date(2022, 3, 28).toISOString()
    },
    {
      productName: "Apple",
      catagory: "Fruits",
      price: "4 / kg",
      image: "apple.jpg",
      desc: "Freshly Picked Apple",
      offerUntil: new Date(2022, 3, 25).toISOString()
    },
    {
      productName: "Pear",
      catagory: "Fruits",
      price: "6 / kg",
      image: "pear1.jpg",
      desc: "Freshly Picked Pear",
    },
    {
      productName: "Banana",
      catagory: "Fruits",
      price: "4 / kg",
      image: "banana1.jpg",
      desc: "Freshly Picked Banana",
    },
  ],
};

// wait until HTML document is loadedn
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
    for (let i of products.data) {
      let card = document.createElement("div");
    
      card.classList.add("card", i.catagory, "hide");
    
      let imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
    
      imgContainer.classList.add("image-container");
    
      let image = document.createElement("img");
      image.setAttribute("src", i.image);
      imgContainer.appendChild(image);
      card.appendChild(imgContainer);
    
      let container = document.createElement("div");
      container.classList.add("container");
    
      let name = document.createElement("h4");
      name.classList.add("product-name");
      name.innerText = i.productName.toUpperCase();
      container.appendChild(name);
    
      let desc = document.createElement("h5");
      desc.innerText = i.desc;
      container.appendChild(desc);
    
      let price = document.createElement("h4");
      price.innerText = "£" + i.price;
      container.appendChild(price);
    
      // if this is an limited offer, attach a timer
      if(i.offerUntil){
          let timer = document.createElement("h3");
          // create a new timer for given date and attach it to the newly created h3
          i.timer = new Timer(i.offerUntil, timer);
          i.timer.start();
          container.appendChild(timer);
      }
      card.appendChild(container);
      document.getElementById("products").appendChild(card);
    }
})
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wraper">
        <div id="search-container">
            <input type="search" name="" id="search-input" placeholder="Search...">
            <button id="search">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('all')">All</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Fruits')">Fruits</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Vegetable')">Vegetable</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Dairy')">Dairy</button>
            <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('Bakery')">Bakery</button>
        </div>
        <div id="products"></div>
        <!-- <div id="timer">0</div> -->
        
    
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

You should wait until the HTML document is loaded before attaching event handlers and alike using the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.

You could also improve your code by not using `innerHTML` and only do the calculation of time difference once. You could then store the difference in days, hours etc. as a class attribute and just decrement that, which will be less calculations.

> Please note: I have adjusted your input so each product can have a Date as an ISO-8601 string when the offer is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am new in Java Script and bit stuck now, please could you write the codes for me what you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, the code is running and exactly I wanted this, though as a newbie I have to digest all properly. Thanks again for your input.